# Как сделать меню Hamburger в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте, можно ли сделать в WPF меню Hamburger? если можно то как? Проект с GitHub не знаю как правильно поставить, не получается. Подскажите, буду благодарен.

Comment: Зачем в десктопе приложении гамбургер? Он только ухудшит юзабилити. Ладно мобильное,где место ограничено. Используйте привычные для пользователей элементы управления - обычное меню или тулбар

Comment: У меня приложение было для людей которым надо чтобы все было недалеко, а то они начнут забывать или перестанут им пользоваться, что гамбургер остается, как хороший способ поддержания пользоваться приложением.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) `View - Other Windows - Package Manager Console`. Выбираем в качестве проекта по умолчанию (Default project) проект, в который нужно установить пакет и пишем:

`PM> Install-Package HamburgerMenu`

2) Далее в окне, в котором вы собираетесь разместить меню добавляем дополнительное пространство имен:

`xmlns:hamburgerMenu="clr-namespace:HamburgerMenu;assembly=HamburgerMenu"`

3) После чего меню можно создать следующим образом:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

       <!-- Не забудьте добавить пространство имен -->
       xmlns:hamburgerMenu="clr-namespace:HamburgerMenu;assembly=HamburgerMenu"
       Title="MainWindow"
       Width="500"
       Height="500"
       mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <hamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenu Background="Blue" MenuIconColor="White" SelectionIndicatorColor="White" MenuItemForeground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <hamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem Text="Home" SelectionCommand="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
        <hamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenuItem Text="Search"/>
    </hamburgerMenu:HamburgerMenu>
</Grid>
```